# Why is my validation on my Laravel form failing and routing to a different page?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and trying to submit a form and check if an input is numeric. But when I get to the validation it routes to a different page.If I remove the validation then everything works correctly.
This is my blade form:pin_verification.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title','Verify Order')
@section('extra_head_info')
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

@endsection


@section('content')
    @if(count($errors) > 0)
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li class="alert alert-danger">{{$error}}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endif


    {{ Form::open(['action' => 'PinVerificationController@pinValidation','id'=>'pin_verification_form']) }}
        We sent a text message to {{$clean_number}}. You should receive it within a few seconds.<br><br>
        {{ Form::label('Pin Code', null, ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
        {{ Form::text('pin_number', null,['placeholder' => 'Pin Code'])}}<br><br>
        Enter a 4 digit pin you received by phone.
        <br>
        <br>
        {{ Form::submit('Verify',['name'=>'validate'])}}

    {{ Form::close() }}
@endsection
```

When I click my submit button on my pin_verification.blade.php form 
I go to my PinVerificationController.php:

```
class PinVerificationController extends Controller
{

    public function pinValidation(Request $request){

        if($request->has('validate')){

            $validator = $this->validate($request,[
                'pin_number' => 'required|numeric'
            ]);
            return redirect("/test/create");
            //return $this->validatePin($request);
        }else{//choosing verification method
            return $this->choosePinVerficationMethod($request);
        }
    }

    public function init(){
        ...
    }

    public function choosePinVerficationMethod(Request $request){
        ...
    }
}
```

My code goes into pinValidation function and into the first if statement  but when it hits the 
`$validator = $this->validate($request,[
     'pin_number' => 'required|numeric'
 ]);`
It routes to my init() function to a different controller, CheckoutController.php
If I remove my validation then my code works correctly and I get redirected to   `redirect("/test/create");`
Why is this happening?

My routes are:

```
Route::get('/order/verify/{encrypted_key}', ['as'=>'pinverification','uses'=>'PinVerificationController@init']);
Route::get('/test/create', ['as'=>'orders_create', 'uses'=>'OrdersController@init']);
Route::post('/order/verify', ['as'=>'pinverification1', 'uses'=>'PinVerificationController@pinValidation']);
Route::get('/order/checkout/{product_id}', ['as'=>'checkout',      'uses'=>'CheckoutController@init']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you aren't actually checking the validation, you're just performing the method, so then naturally it just routes to `/test/create` as per the first return redirect instruction.

Try this instead:

```
public function pinValidation(Request $request){
    if($request->has('validate')){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'pin_number' => 'required|numeric'
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('test/create')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        } else {
            // Success criteria, validation passed.
        }
    } else {
        $this->choosePinVerficationMethod($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **validate** method, you have used here redirects you itself:

```
$validator = $this->validate($request,[
   'pin_number' => 'required|numeric'
]);
```

You should rather use:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request,[
   'pin_number' => 'required|numeric'
]);
```

and then check for:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
   //redirect
};
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874269/laravel-validatormake-vs-this-validate)