# Laravel 5.4 does not redirect after unsuccessful validation

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using basic validation in Laravel (5.4) Controller. If USER submits the form with empty field's the validation is unsuccessful but it won't redirect to the page where the request came from and rather gives me a white blank page. If I click back button on the browser window then I can see the standard error messages on the screen that the fields are empty.

I checked the **laravel.log** and it gives bunch of errors. I have added the headings of the errors below.

> And this issue is with every form on the project. Please help me to
>   solve this issue, **THANKS** in advance.

***Routes:*** 
**web.php**

```
Route::prefix($language)->middleware(['CheckReferer', 'CheckCart'])->group(function() {
    Route::get('/signin', 'Auth\UserLoginController@getSignIn')->name('user.signIn');
    Route::post('/signin', 'Auth\UserLoginController@postSignIn')->name('user.postSignIn');
}
```

**sign-in.blade.php**

```
<form name="form_signup" id="form_signup" action="{{ route('user.postSignIn') }}" method="post">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">

            <!--Header-->
            <div class="form-header blue-gradient">
                <h3><i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{ __('sign-in.sign_in') }}</h3>
            </div>

            <!-- Form validation Errors -->
            @if ($errors->any())
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <ul>
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            @endif
            <!-- END Form validation Errors -->

            <!--Body-->
            <div class="md-form">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope text-blue-color prefix"></i>
                <input type="text" id="user_email" name="user_email" class="form-control" value="">
                <label for="user_email">{{ __('sign-in.your_email') }}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="md-form">
                <i class="fa fa-lock text-blue-color prefix"></i>
                <input type="password" id="user_password" name="user_password" class="form-control" value="">
                <label for="user_password">{{ __('sign-in.password') }}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center">
                {{ csrf_field() }}

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('sign-up.btn_login') }}</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**loginController.php**

```
public function postSignIn(CookieJar $cookieJar, Request $request) {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'user_email' => 'email|required',
            'user_password' => 'required|min:3'
        ]);

        if(Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['user_email' => $request->user_email, 'password' => $request->user_password])) {
            // Successful
            $cookieJar->queue(cookie('userID', Auth::id(), 1440));
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }

        return redirect()->back();

}
```

**laravel.log**

```
local.ERROR: ErrorException: Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:156
Stack trace:
.
.
.
local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::addCookieToResponse() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, null given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php on line 72 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php:170
Stack trace:
.
.
.
local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::encrypt() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, null given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php on line 59 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php:123
Stack trace:
.
.
.
local.ERROR: ErrorException: Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:156
Stack trace:
.
.
.
local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::addCookieToResponse() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, null given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php on line 72 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php:170
Stack trace:
.
.
.
local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::encrypt() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, null given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php on line 59 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php:123
Stack trace:
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution which worked out for me. I wrapped the validation in the try and catch. Below is the code for my issue.

```
try {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'user_email' => 'email|required',
        'user_password' => 'required|min:3'
    ]);
} catch (\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $e){
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include csrf token on form?

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
    @csrf
    ...
</form>
```

You can also change this for the route of the original form

```
//return redirect()->back();
return redirect('user.signIn');
```

Comment: Yes, I have used `{{ csrf_field() }}`. The code execution stops at `$this->validate`. And `return redirect()->back();` works fine in this case but thanks for the suggestion for the *redirect*.

Comment: are you using custom validations?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874269/laravel-validatormake-vs-this-validate

check if you can append
 $this->validate($request, [
            'user_email' => 'email|required',
            'user_password' => 'required|min:3'
        ])->fails()) {
    //
}

or https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#manually-creating-validators

Comment: I am using basic laravel validation but when the validation fails it does not redirect to the previous page. If I click back button on the browser window then I can see the errors messages for the validation.

Comment: Try to append ->fails({return redirect('user.signIn');}) to validate or make a custom one as on the links to rule out options